# Where the term `cross-attention` is first used? (couldn't find the term in attention is all you need paper)

Tags: transformer

I am looking for the paper that first used the term `cross-attention`.

I carefully read the paper `Attention is all you need (NeurIPS 2017)` but couldn't find the term `cross-attention`. I understand that cross-attention could be seen as a modification of self-attention in terms of query, key, and value, but I want to find the exact sentence that first used the term `cross-attention`.

Thank you very much.

[noted picture](https://vaclavkosar.com/ml/transformers-self-attention-mechanism-simplified)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Cross-attention** appeared in CAT[1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.05786.pdf) paper where, for a given image, authors proposed the use of self-attention itself on, first, the 'inner patches' (local information) followed by self-attention between the patches - 'cross patches'.

CrossViT[2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.14899v2.pdf) then used this term and proposed dual-branch transformer architecture to get better *image representations*. They process small-patches and large-patches in separate branches and fuse them by using 'cross-attention fusion'.

**References:**

[1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.05786.pdf) Lin, Hezheng, et al. "[Cat: Cross attention in vision transformer.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.05786.pdf)" 2022 IEEE International Conference on Multimedia and Expo (ICME). IEEE, 2022.

[2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.14899v2.pdf) Chen, Chun-Fu Richard, Quanfu Fan, and Rameswar Panda. "[Crossvit: Cross-attention multi-scale vision transformer for image classification.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.14899v2.pdf)" Proceedings of the IEEE/CVF international conference on computer vision. 2021.

**[Update1]**
As I was watching Sir Karpathy's video on "[Let's build GPT](https://youtu.be/kCc8FmEb1nY?t=4540)", I noticed he mentioned following simple statement at one point:
*"self-attention" just means that the keys and values are produced from the same source as queries. In, "cross-attention", the source of keys and values is different from that of queries.*

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, since the paper 'Attention is all you need' was published in 2017, I will postpone adoption to check whether the term will be used a little earlier than 2021. Thanks!

Comment: As far as I understand, there is not such specific attention as "cross-attention". People have used multiple self-attention (or multi-head attention) blocks from "Attention is all you need" in a single architecture by passing different information through them and called it "cross".
Vaclav Kosar explained this well in his blog: https://vaclavkosar.com/ml/cross-attention-in-transformer-architecture